# vlookup is returning wrong value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling trying to find why my vlookup is not returning the right value.

So I have 2 worksheets where I want to search a code bar in a table and if in that table is exists it returns the item no.

So my first worksheet have

```
ID      InternCode Desription                   CodeBar
10266   #N/D       NUTREA 12-4-6 1 LT           5600993900087
```

ID, InterCode and CodeBar are field type number.

And in the other sheet (Mira), I have all the items internal code, codebar, description and Price.

```
Item No_    Barcode No_     Description         Price
1515150032  5600993900087   NUTREA 12.4.6 1L    1.20
```

So I want to get the Item No_ "1515150032" and Price "1.20".

I set ItemNo, BarCode and Price as field number.

In order to get the item no i'm doing `VLOOKUP(D4;Mira!A:D;1)` and this returns value 9590900018 instead of 1515150032.

Why??

Comment: What is `PROCV` ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm portuguese and I write the portuguese formula. Is vlookup in english :)

Comment: OK. `VLOOKUP(D4;Mira!A:D;1)` has a fourth argument which determines whether an exact match. Try `VLOOKUP(D4;Mira!A:D;1;0)`. But if you are looking up 5600993900087 that must be in the leftmost column of your range - it appears to be in the second column. You might need INDEX/MATCH instead.

Comment: That returns N#D

Comment: See my final remark.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be precise without knowing more about your precise set up, but the picture below should give you an idea. Adjust ranges to suit.

The formula in F2 is `=INDEX(A$6:A$10,MATCH($D$2,$B$6:$B$10,0))`

The formula in G2 is `=INDEX(D$6:D$10,MATCH($D$2,$B$6:$B$10,0))`

[image]

Comment: I've tried that... se my pic pls where INDICE=IDNEX and MATCH=CORRESP

https://ibb.co/JjTBQdk

Comment: The ranges must be single column, as in my example above. The first column is the column you're returning (e.g. item no) and the second is the column containing the barcodes.

Comment: I have the information in different sheets becasue in my sheet "Mira" I have all the items with item no, barcode and other information understand?

Comment: The syntax for different sheets is the same as VLOOKUP - you can work through it manually to add the sheet references.

Comment: All sorted ...?